# How to compute the Hessian using auto differentiation?

Tags: automatic-differentiation, differentiation

Assume that $f$ is defined as a composition of functions:
$$f=f_2 \circ f_1$$
where $f_1:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m_1}$ and $f_2:\mathbb{R}^{m_1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. We can compute the Jacobian $J_f(x)$ using the chain rule:
$$J_f(x) = J_{f_2}(f_1(x))J_{f_1}(x)$$

and we can also compute the Hessian $H_f(x)$:
$$H_f(x) = J_{f_1}(x)^TH_{f_2}(f_1(x))J_{f_1}(x) + J_{f_2}(f_1(x))H_{f_1}(x)$$

[The JAX Autodiff Cookbook](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/autodiff_cookbook.html#hessian-vector-products-using-both-forward-and-reverse-mode) describes two methods for computing the hessian using auto differentiation:

1. forward-over-reverse
2. reverse-over-forward

I don't understand why you would need two applications of automatic differentiation (i.e., reverse then forward or forward then reverse). Why can't we use a single forward mode application to compute $f_1(x)$, $J_{f_1}(x)$, $H_{f_1}(x)$, and then compute $f_2(f_1(x))$, $J_{f_2}(f_1(x))$, $H_{f_2}(f_1(x))$, and then put everything together? Perhaps I am missing something, so it would be helpful if someone could provide a simple example.

Comment: You are aware that  here $H_f$ is an order 3 tensor? Most applications that motivate the forward-reverse combination have a scalar or low-dimensional valued $f:I\!R^n\to I\!R^m$. So if the output dimension is $m$ you would compare propagating $n\times n$ matrices forward to propagating $n\times m$ matrices backwards.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, I am aware that $H_f \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m_1 \times m}$.

Comment: This remark was because you used matrix notation. The matrix operations of the first factor denote different tensor operations in the two terms.

Comment: On a side note, you may also compute the Hessian via the use of hyperdual numbers. In the same spirit as the complex step they allow for machine precision estimation of the Jacobian and Hessian of a function provided that the function supports hyperdual numbers. Could be useful for error checking for example.

Comment: BTW, Hessians becoming Rank-3 tensors make chain rule a awkward to describe. Structure is still the same as in matrix case, but to make it precise you need to specify indices. Using Einstein summation notation, chain rule is $$\nabla^2 f(G(x))^i_{lm} = \nabla^2 f^{i}_{jk} \nabla G^j_l \nabla G^k_m + \nabla f^i_n \nabla^2 G^n_{lm} $$. To keep track of indices, I use Penrose [diagrams](https://i.imgur.com/kqfGoym.png)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : Or you separate non-linear arguments and linear derivation vectors. Then one could write $(f\circ g)''(x)[·,·]=f''(g(x))[g'(x)·,g'(x)·]+f'(g(x))g''(x)[·,·]$, which is approximately a horizontal version of the diagrams.

Comment: @LutzLehmann interesting! That's indeed much better than Einstein notation. Do you have a reference to any place which uses this notation?

Answer (score 2):

Hessian is the derivative of derivative, so you can compute it using using two passes of first-order autodiff.

What you are describing in your formulas is symbolic automatic differentiation (AD) which is a different algorithm than what Jax implements with autodiff. Incidentally, I prototyped symbolic AD [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BDFc9poKybcxeu_RpGGL7_HjqlLjuqfq?usp=sharing) to compare its speed relative to classical autodiff. It's faster when intermediate functions have structured Jacobians (ie, Jacobian matrix is diagonal, low-rank, sparse, etc)

Regarding Jax implementation, it implements algorithms known as "forward" and "reverse" modes, which are specialized algorithms for applying chain rule numerically in a particular order.

Multivariate chain rule can be viewed as matrix multiplication where matrices are Jacobians. Finding optimal order of multiplication is known as the [matrix chain problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication) and there are many solutions, but "left-to-right" and "right-to-left" orders occur most often in deep learning, hence getting their own names and dedicated implementations as "reverse mode" and "forward mode" respectively.

If you compute derivative of scalar quantity w.r.t to vector and intermediate dimensions are large, the most efficient order is left-to-right. Here's an example of computing derivative of f1(f2(f3(f4(x)))) where intermediate dimensions are all 10 and output $y$ is scalar.

[image]

Meanwhile, derivative of vector quantity w.r.t to scalar, "right-to-left" order is most efficient. Here's an example of with f1(f2(f3(f4(x)))) where intermediate dimensions are all 10 and input $x$ is scalar.

[image]

If you need to differentiate vector w.r.t. to n-dimensional vector, which is the case when computing the Hessian, you can break it into $n$ problems of differentiate "vector w.r.t to a scalar", apply forward-mode to each problem, then concatenate results together.

Similar trick can be applied to use reverse-mode, hence you can choose whether do use "reverse" or "forward" mode for each stage of autodiff. There are two stages giving you 4 choices, reverse/reverse, reverse/forward, forward/reverse, forward/forward. If your function is scalar valued, with vector valued inputs of size $n$, then computing Hessian using forward-over-reverse is going to be factor of $n$ faster than forward-over-forward. (first stage of computing Hessian would need $n$ passes of forward, but only 1 pass of reverse)

PS: if some intermediate dimensions are small, neither "forward" nor "reverse" mode are good choices, and needs "mixed" or "cross-country" mode differentiation, an example is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QrcW2Xv3jcL6V_Jtsjy5HJTlyLF-76-S#scrollTo=u3zW8GjTcgjg)

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "structured Jacobians"? 

2) So I guess autodiff is just differentiating by applying the chain rule to some function. To get the Hessian, we would have to differentiate twice, hence two applications of autodiff. But that means that the algorithm must output a mathematical function, not just the function evaluated at a specific point. Is that correct?

Comment: 1) Structured Jacobian=Jacobian matrix is structured. IE, diagonal, low-rank, etc. A layer applied pointwise (ie, sigmoid, relu) has diagonal Jacobian. I would say everything except Linear layer has a structured Jacobian 2) No, you are thinking symbolic AD. Autodiff computes derivative at a specific point

Comment: I don't think this answers the question at all.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov 2) If AD does not output a mathematical function, and only outputs the derivative at a specific point, then there is no way to compute a second derivative...

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Do you have any references for this: "A layer applied pointwise (ie, sigmoid, relu) has diagonal Jacobian."?

Comment: @user572780 take a function which squares each component of input vector and compute its Jacobian by hand. You should get a multiple of the identity

Comment: @FedericoPoloni the link in question points to `jax.hvp`, I'm guessing because docs for `jax.hessian` are missing the section on autograd modes. However, 'forward-over-reverse' also applies to `jax.hessian`

Answer (score 1):

The goal of that code in JAX is not computing the Hessian $H_{f,x}$: it is computing (given a vector $v$) the product $H_{f,x}v$ *without* forming the full Hessian, because in many cases it would be too expensive and too large to fit in memory.

Your suggested solution forms the full Hessian, instead.

Comment: I understand this, but I am not sure this answers my question. You can right multiply the Hessian $H_f$ and then sum the vectors to find $H_fv$. My question is why do we compute $f'$ first and then apply AD a second time for $f''$, when we can compute $f'$ and $f''$ in the same application? That way we don't need to repeat calculations, e.g., $f'$ at a specific point.

Comment: @user572780 you could do it. Jax doesn't do it because it started as numpy autograd with the goal of computing first derivatives at specific points.

Comment: Calling [jax.hessian](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.hessian.html) forms the full Hessian. This is suboptimal because Hessians are usually structured. For instance, Hessian of softmax function is a sum of a rank-1 and a diagonal matrix. You would need to implement chain rule with support for rank-1/diagonal structure to make this efficient. Instead it implements "forward" and "reverse" algorithms which lose this structure. "Forward over reverse" is better than "forward over forward" for scalar functions, but still worse than symbolic chain rule

Comment: BTW, calling `jax.diag(jax.hessian(...))` is what you do in Jax to obtain diagonal Hessian preconditioner, can't do it with Hessian-vector-products.